Why is there network traffic from the idle process in `cgroup/skb`?
Here's the eBPF code:
void stat_traffic_impl(struct __sk_buff* skb) {
    switch (skb->family) {
    case AF_INET:
        bpf_printk("%u -> %u", skb->local_ip4, skb->remote_ip4);
        bpf_printk("%pI4h -> %pI4h", skb->local_ip4, skb->remote_ip4);
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }
}

SEC("cgroup/skb")
int stat_traffic(struct __sk_buff* skb) {
    stat_traffic_impl(skb);
    return true;  // let packet pass
}

Here's part of the output:
             cat-554297  [000] ..s11 48045.305791: bpf_trace_printk: 1562355904 -> 3395707859
             cat-554297  [000] ..s11 48045.305791: bpf_trace_printk: 0.0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.0
          <idle>-0       [001] ..s21 48045.305824: bpf_trace_printk: 1562355904 -> 3395707859
          <idle>-0       [001] ..s21 48045.305825: bpf_trace_printk: 0.0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.0
             cat-554297  [000] ..s11 48045.305839: bpf_trace_printk: 1562355904 -> 3395707859
             cat-554297  [000] ..s11 48045.305840: bpf_trace_printk: 0.0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.0
          <idle>-0       [000] ..s21 48045.305895: bpf_trace_printk: 1562355904 -> 3563480019
          <idle>-0       [000] .Ns21 48045.305898: bpf_trace_printk: 0.0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.0
          <idle>-0       [001] ..s21 48045.306075: bpf_trace_printk: 1562355904 -> 3563480019
          <idle>-0       [001] ..s21 48045.306079: bpf_trace_printk: 0.0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.0
          <idle>-0       [000] ..s21 48045.306103: bpf_trace_printk: 1562355904 -> 3395707859
          <idle>-0       [000] .Ns21 48045.306105: bpf_trace_printk: 0.0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.0
          <idle>-0       [001] ..s21 48045.306126: bpf_trace_printk: 1562355904 -> 3563480019
          <idle>-0       [001] ..s21 48045.306129: bpf_trace_printk: 0.0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.0
          <idle>-0       [001] ..s21 48045.306131: bpf_trace_printk: 1562355904 -> 3395707859
          <idle>-0       [001] ..s21 48045.306133: bpf_trace_printk: 0.0.0.0 -> 0.0.0.0

I want to know:

Why %pI4h always results in 0.0.0.0?
Why is there so much network traffic from the idle process? What exactly does the idle process do here?

Environment:

Distro: Arch Linux
Kernel: Linux 6.10.3
Clang Version: 18.1.8
Libbpf Version: 1.4.3


What happens if you use %pI4 instead of %pI4h ?

@Dai The same, always 0.0.0.0.

Ok I know why $pI4 doesn't work. The argument should be a pointer.

...but you're using %pI4 - not $pI4

Sorry, typo. It's %pI4.


Why %pI4h always results in 0.0.0.0?

As you figured yourself, it's because that format specifier expects a pointer. This line should read:
bpf_printk("%pI4h -> %pI4h", &skb->local_ip4, &skb->remote_ip4);

That's why the first bpf_printk shows actual IP values, while the second doesn't.


Why is there so much network traffic from the idle process? What exactly does the idle process do here?

This isn't actually the idle process. It's just that the kernel doesn't have a process associated with those packets and therefore defaults to PID 0.
You can confirm this by calling bpf_get_current_pid_tgid from your BPF code. You will then see that for all <idle>-0 cases, bpf_get_current_pid_tgid returns 0.

Thanks! In what case a packet has no associated process?

In case of traffic that isn't emitted/received by a userspace process or in case the packets haven't been associated with the userspace process yet. I'd recommend dumping more information about those packets to understand what they are.
